# Generating ER-diagram from an existing database schema

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram

Similar questions has been asked more than 10 years ago.  I have tried to search the web for the last two days, and read numerous pages all over the place.  Unfortunately, I am still not finding a good answer.

This question should not have been tied to any particular database, but my particular server is mysql 5.6.12.  I tried mysql-workbench, and it could not generate the links between the entities even though my database has clear foreign key constraints defined.

In the past I have used a program from Sybase, and it worked fine and need to pay.
I have seen one from Oracle, not sure this one is good or not. It might be a time for people to share experiences here.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a pattern that usually people who has no problems won't visit this site. Just to make a simple answer to my own question.

Mysql-workbench can display relationships, but if you have one single error in the schema, then not a single one will show up.  I found DbSchema a better alternative, and it is not expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen interesting projects on sourceforge:

- schemacrawler  --> http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/
- schemaspy      --> http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/

I've never used them but they looks good with maven integration, programatically and command line modes, and many other stuff.